# Solving $\int_{0}^{+ \infty} \frac{x \cos(x)}{x^4 + 4 a^4} dx$ with residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We also have the condition $a > 0$. My attempt was to, as usual, define $f(z) = \displaystyle\frac{z e^{iz}}{z^4 + 4 a^4}$. Then I tried to integrate $f$ over a curve $\gamma$ which goes from $0$ to $R > 0$, then travels along a circle to $iR$, and then goes to $0$ through the imaginary axis (i.e. a quarter of a circle). My problem is that the integral of $f$ along the imaginary axis seems hard to handle. I can't tell what it is (it certainly doesn't go to zero). Computing the residues of $f$ is easy, but what contour should I pick?

Comment: Are you certain that this is the correct integrand?  And why are you looking to evaluate using contour integration?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x\sin x$ in the numerator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first, since $x^4+4a^4 = (x^2+2a^2)^2-4a^2 x^2 = (x^2-2ax+2a^2)(x^2+2ax+2a^2)$, we have:
$$ \frac{x}{x^4+4a^4} = \frac{1}{4a}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-2ax+2a^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+2ax+2a^2}\right)$$
hence it is enough to compute:
$$ I_a = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2-2ax+2a^2}\,dx =  \int_{-a}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x+a)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx$$
that, however, is not an elementary integral, but depends on the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and the [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).